# How to force a mac os combo update after a newer security update

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update

Yesterday i updated my Macbook Pro 15" 2018 with the latest 2020-002 security update and one of the left USB-C port stops working. Really weird. It have always been working fine.
Today i wanted to try re-applying the 10.14.6 Combo update but it want allow me.
I found out ofcause the 10.14.6 Combo update out right now is not working if you used the latest 2020-002 security update because it changes the build number. I hope Apple will make a new 10.14.6 Combo update.
But until they do. Does anyone know a way how to cheat or fool the system so i can re-apply the older 10.14.6 Combo update now ?
There must be a way or a file where this build information is located and can be changed some how, i guess, or hope.

I forgot to make a new backup of my computer before i used the 2020-002 security update. Stupid.
So the only way i can check if it's the 2020-002 that broke my left USB-C port. Is to re-install the 10.14.6 Combo update again so the 2020-002 will disappear.

Thanks

Comment: You can't 'fool' it as the manifest will be wrong. Say the security update changed a file in System, one that hadn't been updated or changed since 10.14.0, Forcing the last combo over it wouldn't know that file was new, so it wouldn't put it back to what it was before. Multiply that by however many files ...

Comment: okay so there is no way to re-apply that 10.14.6 Combo Update after i used the latest 2020-002 security update before Apple makes a new 10.14.6 Combo Update with the 2020-002 inside ?

Comment: I doubt they'll make one before 10.14.7, but that's just a guess. If you look at the release history for High Sierra, there hasn't been an update to the combo since the last 2 security updates.

Comment: ah i see.I guess your right there. mmm nothing to do then. i´m sure its the 2020-002 security update that killed my left USB-C port. It worked 10 min before i used 2020-002 and didn't 2 min after i used 2020-002 :( i know it sounds strange, but i can only be the reason

Comment: What about use the full MacOS 10.14.6 image like i would use the Combo Update ? Will that delete my system or just replace all system files like if i used the Combo ?

Comment: You'd probably have to nuke & pave to get back to an earlier version.